# Why can't I convert from Animism to Catholic?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I send a missionary [envoy](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Envoys), but he does not appear to make any progress!

In EU4, are some religions are "weaker" so you can **never** convert weak/unpopular religion to a higher one, such as Islam or Christianity?

Comment: When you hover over the progress in the religion tab, it should say something like "making 0.0% progress a month due to". What are the reasons and effects it lists in there?

Comment: no, it says "with this speed we will never convert them "

Comment: But it should still list all the modifiers. One of them will probably eclipse the others. For example, in my Castilian game I have had some events that converted provinces to Protestant with a -25% local missionary strength penalty. With bonuses totalling around 6%, my missionaries have no chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your missionary strength is to low, you can not convert a province and it will say:

"with this speed we will never convert them "

And most likely "making 0.0% progress a month due to".

Have you looked a the religion icon in the province menu? if you hover over it, it will give all positive and negative bonuses

Comment: i know the answer now! You need to see missionary maintenance in religion tab. It was 0.0 - i spent 0 money on this activity. I increased it to max and now i can convert people (catholic ->animist)